# CDN Images don't Load (OpenGraph)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cdn, facebook-opengraph

I setup in my wordpress blog OpenGraph. For image I insert this code (wordpress):
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21385868/codeog.jpg

the result in site page (html is):
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21385868/resog.jpg

if I share article on the facebook, image don't appear. But, if I disable my cdn, image appear on the facebook.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Advanced CDN settings add to Rejected User Agents

```
    FacebookExternalHit/1.1
    FacebookExternalHit/1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook blocks images that are hosted on CDNs.